# MacBook will not boot to recovery after setting boot args

Tags: macos, macbook-pro, startup, recovery

I booted to recovery using Command R.

I was trying to get to safe mode so I opened a terminal window here and ran:

```
nvram boot-args="-x"
```

and then I rebooted. The system did not go to safe mode.

Rebooted again pressing Command R, but the system will not boot to recovery. All I get now is a circle with a line through it. How can I fix this?

Answer (score 1):

1. Boot with ⌘S to boot to single-user mode.
2. Remove the boot arguments by running `nvram -d boot-args`.
3. Reboot by running `reboot`.

For future reference, you can boot to safe mode for a specific boot by holding ⇧ on boot without needing to set any boot arguments.